# DoubleBinding for lower and higher element on lines's list

Tags: javafx, binding

I have list of line's connectors.

I would like to draw a horizontal line between them, using bindings of startX and endX properties. unfortunatelly I have problem to write correct Binding function.

```
  startX = Bindings.when(connectorsIsEmpty)
                    .then(0.0)
                    .otherwise(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                            () -> connectors.stream().min(Comparator.comparingDouble(value -> value.getLine().getStartX())), connectors
                    ));
```

With this code, I have error on createDoubleBinding ("cannot resolve method")

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter `createDoubleBinding` expects is a `Callable<Double>`. `Stream<T>.min` returns an `Optional<T>` though.

Assuming `connectorsIsEmpty` is `Bindings.isEmpty(connectors)`, you could simplify the whole thing:

```
startX = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                () -> connectors.stream().mapToDouble(value -> value.getLine().getStartX()).min().orElse(0d),
                connectors);
```

Comment: startX on Line could change, it will be also prise en charge ?

Comment: No, unless you're using the right kind of `ObservableList`: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList(javafx.util.Callback)

Comment: Which is right kind ??  Because connectors are placed in ObservableArrayList

Comment: `FXCollections.<Line>observableArrayList(line -> new Observable[]{ line.startXProperty() })`. If you create the list this way every time one of the observables returned by the `Callback` changes for an element of the list, an update change is triggered for the list. The binding is notified of this change assuming you specify the list as dependency...